# Summing numbers function

Tags: python-2.7

```
def sumnum():
n = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
n = int(n)

if n.isdigit() == False:
    print "wrong input, type a number"
else:
    x = (n*(n+1))/2
    print "Sum is", x
```

This is supposed to be a simple function for calculating sum from user input. Alas, when I type a number I get error.

Comment: What does the error say? Try `print("Sum is ", x)` or `print "Sum is %s" % 2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several errors, but the compiler tells step by step what could be the problem. First code formatting, then the `print` function and finally the place where you check for the "non numeric value". Anyway the working solution could look like.

```
def sumnum():
    n = input("Enter a number: ")

    if n.isdigit() == False:
        print ("wrong input, type a number")
    else:
        n = int(n)
        x = (n*(n+1))/2
        print ("Sum is", x)
```